# how to get uri from firebase storage and save it cloud firestore in android(java)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here  i added the code which i'm working on. i tried  as said in [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) but image get uploaded in Firebase Storage but the Uri is not get updated in Cloud Firestore database. what am i missing.?
**java file:**

```
fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString()).addOnSuccessListener(authResult -> {
                FirebaseUser user =fAuth.getCurrentUser();

                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Account Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 StorageReference Image_path = sRef.child("Profile_Images").child(user.getUid() + ".jpg");
                Image_path.putFile(mainImageURI).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Image_path.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                Uri download_uri = uri;
                                DocumentReference sc=fStore.collection("image").document(user.getUid());
                                Map<String,String> useInfo = new HashMap<>();
                                useInfo.put("Profile Pic",download_uri.toString());
                                sc.set(useInfo);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        String setupError = e.getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "IMAGE Error : " + setupError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

**Rule:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a complete listener to the set() operation? Besides that, please edit your question and add the Firestore rules.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge @AlexMamo. It worked when i added complete listener to the set() operation. As you asked i edited my qn too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding complete listener to the set()

```
   fStore.collection("Users").document(user.getUid()).set(useInfo).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }else{
                                            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "FireStore Error : " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                // Handle failures
                                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "FireStore Error : " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
```